# Input Value Converted To String

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Recently I've been creating a game, and I've been creating a Menu. 
At the beginning the player opens the Menu and enters a name into a UI Text Field, which I will convert to a string, so the player may be called that name throughout the storyline.

I've come across another Script on this website:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class GUIFieldTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject playerName;

    public void Start ()
    {
        var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        var se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        se.AddListener(SubmitName);
        input.onEndEdit.AddListener(SubmitName);

        //or simply use the line below,
        //input.onEndEdit = se;  // This also works
    }

    private void SubmitName(string arg0)
    {
        Debug.Log(arg0);
    }
}
```

I have tweaked this code so I can include a prefab of the Text Field as a GameObject, however I have recieved an error saying:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object GUIFieldTest.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GUIFieldTest.cs:13)

I understand that this error means that there is nothing assigned, and I understand how to fix the NullReferenceException. I am able to run the game, however the game freezes and the text field is not clickable. You cannot enter any text.

I know this is a very simple question, but it would be great for an explanation.

Comment: I am not really familiar with Unity, but I know that a `NullReferenceException` means you are trying to access a member on an objec that is `Null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>()` should be

```
var input = playerName.GetComponent<InputField>().
```

When you use `gameObject.GetComponent`, it will only find components on the GameObject the script is attached to.

I assume that your `InputField` GameOBject is the `playerName` variable.

If this is not true the do  `var input = GameObject.Find("YourInputFieldGameOBject").GetComponent<InputField>()`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Programmer, it works perfectly and the game has been un-frozen!